# Relative Layout giving a lot of trouble

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tc"
        android:layout_marginLeft="185dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
        >

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/tc_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/count_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tc"
                android:layout_mar
            />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tc_icon_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textColor="#f7e906"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />       
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have somehow managed to make the image and the text views overlap each other (which I wanted). Now, I want them to be placed to the bottom left corner of their parent RelativeLayout (with id 'tc').... However, they just wouldn't move.

If I used alignParentBottom.... the entire relative layout stretches across the screen and aligns to its parent relativeLayout.

Please help. Thanks! :)

Comment: can you place a sketch of layout ?

Comment: provide layout sketch ...........

Comment: alignParentBottom and parent layout_height = wrap_content are contradicting with each other. Apply some height to the layout and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. @Fahad, your observation looks right.
However, I have used FrameLayout instead of Relative. Next time I'll try your solution. Though, I have a question. Why and how should I declare height to the relative layout when I want to place an image inside of it? Say, the image is 300x200 px wide, should I be then declaring layout_width as 300px?

Comment: well your approach for wrap_content is great but make sure you use it cumulatively, by which i mean do not cause other things to disturb wrap_content, like just what you did now.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna overlap an image and a textview, simplw use a [`android:drawableleft`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) or ony position where you want.

For example:

`<TextView

                android:id="@+id/tc_icon_text"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"

                android:text="1"

                android:layout_gravity="bottom"

                android:textColor="#f7e906"

                android:textStyle="bold"

                android:drawableleft="@drawable/yourimage.jpg"/>`

This will give you an image on the left of your textview. Check it out

Comment: Could you give a little bit more explanation? Like how to use it? Maybe I can google on how to use drawableLeft. Thanks!

Comment: @ParikksitBhisay: See my edit. I've also given the link on my answer